# Was Jesus raised 'for our justification' or 'because of' it?

Tags: greek, romans

In the NASB, Romans 4:25 (emphasis mine) reads:

> He who was delivered over because of our transgressions, and was
>   raised ***because of*** our justification.

However, in the ESV (emphasis mine) it reads:

> ...who was delivered up for our trespasses and raised ***for*** our
>   justification.

These are very different statements. Was Jesus raised 'for our justification' or 'because of' it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Greek text for Romans 4:25 (from the NA28, emphasis mine) reads:

> ὃς παρεδόθη διὰ τὰ παραπτώματα ἡμῶν καὶ ἠγέρθη ***διὰ*** τὴν δικαίωσιν
>   ἡμῶν.

[The preposition διὰ followed by an accusative generally has a gloss of "on account of" or "because of," but could also carry the connotation "for the sake of."](http://www.wenstrom.org/downloads/written/word_studies/greek/dia.pdf) It *almost always* carries the force of the NASB translation, but could also contain the sense of the ESV (although I suspect this concession is only made in many resources because of this passage, which lends more strength to the causal sense). The NET chose to translate it as follows (emphasis mine):

> He was given over because of our transgressions and was raised ***for
>   the sake of*** our justification.

**My main problem is that the exact same preposition followed by an accusative is almost always translated as causal in the preceding clause** ("He was given over ***because of*** our transgressions"), **and yet when the exact same construction appears the second time in the exact same sentence, people translate it differently** (the ESV is at least consistent). Despite this translation choice (similar to the ESV), the NET translators acknowledge that the Greek carries the causal sense brought out in the NASB translation:

> *Grk* “because of.” However, in light of the unsatisfactory sense 
>   that a causal nuance  would here suggest, it has been argued that the second
>   διά (dia) is prospective rather than retrospective (D. Moo, Romans
>   [NICNT], 288-89). The difficulty of this interpretation is the
>   structural balance that both διά phrases provide (“given over because
>   of our transgressions…raised because of our justification”). However
>   the poetic structure of this verse strengthens the likelihood that the
>   clauses each have a different force.

The NET translators further elaborate on the poetic sense:

> Many scholars regard Rom 4:25 to be poetic or hymnic. These terms are
>   used broadly to refer to the genre of writing, not to the content.
>   There are two broad criteria for determining if a passage is poetic or
>   hymnic: “(a) stylistic: a certain rhythmical lilt when the passages
>   are read aloud, the presence of parallelismus membrorum (i.e., an
>   arrangement into couplets), the semblance of some metre, and the
>   presence of rhetorical devices such as alliteration, chiasmus, and
>   antithesis; and (b) linguistic: an unusual vocabulary, particularly
>   the presence of theological terms, which is different from the
>   surrounding context” (P. T. O’Brien, Philippians [NIGTC], 188-89).
>   Classifying a passage as hymnic or poetic is important because
>   understanding this genre can provide keys to interpretation. However,
>   not all scholars agree that the above criteria are present in this
>   passage.

The NASB translation is most faithful to the literal sense of the Greek in this passage, but scholars who are troubled by the "unsatisfactory sense that a causal nuance would here suggest" have proposed alternative ways of translating this passage that actually change the natural emphasis given to the preposition διὰ (for theological reasons). I personally think it is best to translate this passage as it is written (as the NASB has) with a footnote that indicates that the line may be poetic or carry the sense of "for the sake of" in this context. This would be the most consistent, especially since the preceding clause in the same sentence is also best translated as causal.

Comment: I actually love the ESV here. The English “for” carries both possible nuances of διὰ + acc. - “because of” and “for the sake of.” I realize the latter is less common for διὰ, but didn’t he *just use this* in v. 23 and again in 24? [NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%204&version=NASB): “for his(/our) sake”!

Comment: Honestly I think your suggestion is most consistent with the literal sense of the Greek and with what Paul had said elsewhere in Romans: "Romans 5:9-10 9 Since, therefore, *we have now been justified by his blood,* much more shall we be saved by him from the wrath of God. 10 For if while we were enemies we were reconciled to God by the death of his Son, much more, now that we are reconciled, shall we be saved by his life."

Answer (score -1):

In Greek the causal preposition 'dia' allows and at times even seems to require a final meaning. (Aristotle had described four causes: material, formal, effective, a n d  final cause, which all four respond to the question 'dia ti?' - why?).

Western sciences have - in the wake and philosophical decline after evolution theory depreciated the concept of finality as purely cultural. The end does -  in science -  not count as a cause (and reason) any more, because nature - according to modernists - can not have purpose.

Meanings (like words) once they are lost are hard to regain. The fourth cause - the final and prospective - has gotten widely disregarded as overly scholastic and biased towards the presuppositions of any given theological (and teleological) concept.

The distinction between causality and finality (almost to an opposition) is a modern one. As the English particle 'for' allows for either meaning (and is short) it is perhaps the best choice to translate the Greek 'dia' in this context. (The change from the retrospective to the prospective dia even adds to the parallel.)

There is indeed a beauty in the wording:

paredothe dia ta paraptomata hemon -
kai egerthe dia ten dikaiosin hemon

given over for the stepping over of us -
raised up for the justification of us

In Mark 2:27  there is a similar use of 'dia':

to sabbaton dia ton anthropon egeneto
kai ouk ho anthropos dia to sabbaton

the Sabbath came to be for the human
and not the human for the Sabbath

Here again it seems quite natural to understand
'dia' as being used in its final sense (of purpose).

If possible, a translation that wants to be faithful to the rhythm and emphasis and weight of the expression, should not render one small particle (here: dia) by two (three) or even four words (like these: because - by cause - of, for the sake of).

Comment: Please clarify your actual response to the question. I don't see how [Aristotle's four causes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_causes) is relevant as they actually have nothing to do with the meaning of the preposition as much as nature itself. Also, as it stands this is more of a comment than an answer. Explain how it is relevant (i.e. identify some more sources closer to the writing of Romans as well. Aristotle predates the writing of Romans by approximately 380 years. His thoughts on a preposition may be somewhat anachronistic - but not necessarily).

Comment: Let me reiterate that I'm open to this being a good answer, I'm just not following how you're connecting the dots. Essentially I'm asking you to ["show your work"](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-does-show-your-work-mean-in-the-context-of-exegesis) when it comes to your logic / train of thought here.

Comment: I mentioned Aristotle because he understands an end as a cause. And by asking for this (final) cause - dia ti  - he comments on this aspect of the meaning of dia. The thing about the sciences I mentioned to remind of our training in disregarding finality as a cause.

Comment: can you provider a source so I (and other users) can read where Aristotle comments on the meaning of the preposition? Everything I've found focuses on Aristotle addressing the answer to the question "why?" (δἱα τἱ;), as this is the foundation of what we call "science." Just because the question uses the preposition δἱα does not mean Aristotle is commenting on that meaning of the word itself. He is critiquing Plato's philosophy of Forms. Unless I'm missing something....

Comment: If Aristotle had developed his thoughts not before the time of Paul, it would be of lesser value as it may not have reached Paul and his readers. In fact Aristotle did not invent that meaning of 'dia'. It was already there. As it is in the English 'for'. I will add a citation where he used dia with final meaning, if you wish so. With or without Aristotle Paul obviously used it in that sense as in the other (final and causal in the narrower sense of the word).

Comment: We seem to be chasing Aristotle while we are having Paul already. The philosopher's thoughts on the four causes are undisputed - you supplied a link. However, they do not add much more than a little nuance to the debated verse. (We have come to a point where he disturbs more than he helps.) Perhaps you are right in that: we should have stayed with Paul.

Comment: No @hannes I think there might be something to what you're saying, I would just like to read Aristotle for myself to see if he is indeed commenting on the preposition's meaning. Nothing I've found indicates this, he is merely using it to ask a question about the meaning of existence/being itself. Please supply a source for where Aristotle specifically discusses the meaning of the preposition.

Comment: This link shows a discussion of some divergent opinions about Aristotle's use of 'dia' (strictly causal vs. final) in his Nikomachean Ethics. http://books.google.at/books?id=RoKZuVwgd_gC&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&ots=0UI_JDdGLJ&dq=aristoteles+cause+final+dia&hl=de&output=html_text

Comment: that is very interesting - whether or efficient or final, it is still a causative sense (further reinforcing the NASB translation), only it could mean that justification has already occurred or that it will one day come. Thanks for the source. You should work it into your answer and quote/cite it.

Comment: with your permission, I'll even edit the response.

Comment: @hannes I'm having a hard time following all of this. How does this actually answer the question? Please bring the concepts/assertions that you're setting forth to bear on the question as it stands and please do it in the answer. As it stands it seems like you're substituting the means of exploration (dia ti ... "through/for what?") with the content of the exploration itself. It seems like a stretch to correlate in investigative question with the actual content.